# Should I use BigInteger rather than parsing integers from String?

Tags: java, performance, parsing, numbers, biginteger

I am working with large numbers in Java. I don't know if I should `parse` `String` to `BigInteger` once, and calculate `mod` of that number, or if I should better divide that `String` into segments and `parse` those segments to `int` and calculate `mod` like that.

I am striving for best performance. Which is the better way?

Comment: Why not try both options and then benchmark?  It will be a great learning experience.

Comment: If you do decide to benchmark it, make sure to avoid the [common mistakes people make](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java).

Comment: BigInteger is implemented with an `int[]`. The mod operation has two different algorithms, chosen based on various conditions, to achieve good performance. It's unlikely that you can do much better (unless you use case is very specific and you can take some shortcuts that are not possible in a general purpose class)...

Comment: We almost need a special close category for these performance questions. Just measure it.

Comment: why was this downvoted? it doesn't seem to me to be that embarrassing to ask.

Answer (score 0):

`BigInteger` is made to do such things, and current implementations are pretty well optimized.

Also, I wonder how you want to partition the string so that you actually get the correct `mod` result using `long`s or `int`s, without having to take care of a number of corner cases and without intensive testing.

So while I agree that, if you really want to implement your own algorithm, you should actually profile this and compare the performance to `BigInteger`, *I personally don't think that trying to reinvent the wheel is necessary*. I would use `BigInteger`.